# APEX collection only shows 10 fields

Tags: oracle-apex

I created an APEX collection using CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY, where underlying query pulls about 11-12 columns. But when I view the collection via Session, the collection only has 10 columns, c001 through c010. Why doesn't it show the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose to see the other columns by using the IR functionality - Actions, Select, then choose columns.

[image]

Alternatively, you could play and manipulate your collections [from SQL Developer](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2018/09/remove-duplicate-from-oracle-apex-collection.html)

Or you could use [join session](https://oos-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oos_util_apex/#join_session-procedure) to query your APEX session collections from SQL Developer.

Comment: Scott, how can I get some of the numeric fields to be displayed as n00x instead of c00x uisng CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY? I cannot find anything in the documentation

Comment: The documentation for that API states " These columns in the SELECT clause populates the 50 character attributes of the collection (C001 through C050)", so I think you can only populate the c columns using these. Add_members allow specifying numerics. Depending on what you're solving, you could contemplate defining your own table, so you can use indexes.